# meta tag X-UA-Compatible IE-edge causes problems

Tags: html

Recently we have added a new menu bar to our website that required the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

However, this has caused some problems further down the line:

```
<Script Language="VBScript">
        Function vbMsg()
            testVal = MsgBox(**numbers of text strings for messagebox contents**)
            isChoice = testVal
        End Function
    </Script>                                   

    <Script Language="JavaScript">
        var isChoice = 0;
        function callAlert(){
            vbMsg()
            if (isChoice == 6) {
//              return (true);
                location.href = "<%= Request("SCRIPT_NAME")%>?Action=SaveMap&Save=True";
            }
            else {
                location.href = "<%= Request("SCRIPT_NAME")%>?Action=SaveMap&Save=False";
//              return (false);
            }
        }
    </Script>
```

This gives an error message that vbMsg is not defined. With the previous meta tag this never happened:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/css; charset=UTF-8">
```

Any clues how to solve this problem?

Comment: text/css?! Why are you claiming your HTML document is CSS?

Comment: Anyway, the content type meta data sets the character encoding for the document, it has nothing to do with the rendering engine at all. You can't substitute `<meta http-equiv="content-type"` for `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` are they are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because VB Script is no longer supported in IE11: [VBScript is no longer supported in IE11 edge mode (Microsoft)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, the solution is of course to rewrite your vbMsg() function in JavaScript.

Comment: … and the solution is to rewrite in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

According to information from Microsoft, [VBScript is no longer supported in IE11 edge mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The following tag gives you IE 10 mode (where VBScript still works) in IE 11:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

You need to check whether this is sufficient for making the new code work.

A better long-term solution is to convert your VBScript code to JavaScript code, but you need to consider the costs against the expected lifetime of your software (site/application).